# What is the fastest way to get an HTML document node using XPath and the HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

In my application I need to get to get the URL of the image of a blog post. In order to do this I'm using the HtmlAgilityPack.

This is the code I have so far:

```
static string GetBlogImageUrl(string postUrl)
{
    string imageUrl = string.Empty;

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string htmlString = client.DownloadString(postUrl);
        HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlString);
        string xPath = "/html/body/div[contains(@class, 'container')]/div[contains(@class, 'content_border')]/div[contains(@class, 'single-post')]/main[contains(@class, 'site-main')]/article/header/div[contains(@class, 'featured_image')]/img";
        HtmlNode node = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xPath);
        imageUrl = node.GetAttributeValue("src", string.Empty);
    }

    return imageUrl;
}
```

The problem is that this is too slow, when I did some tests I noticed that It takes about three seconds to extract the URL of the image in the given page. Which it's a problem when I'm loading a feed and trying to red several articles.

I tried to use the absolute xpath of the element I want to load, but I didn't noticed any improvement. Is there a faster way to achieve this?

Comment: could you share the html structure you are parsing?

Comment: It really depends on your network connection and also that server response. Xpath will not slow down your app cause once the document is loaded to your memory, it's super fast.

Comment: @HungCao I'm trying to parse a blog post from a corporate blog in order to get the featured image. Here's one example. http://blog.cedrotech.com/5-tendencias-mobile-que-sua-empresa-precisa-acompanhar/

Comment: Check my answer, I tried using just HtmlAgilityPack without WebClient

Comment: @HungCao Thank you. I will try tomorrow when I'm back to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code and see if it's faster or not?

```
string Url = "http://blog.cedrotech.com/5-tendencias-mobile-que-sua-empresa-precisa-acompanhar/";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
var featureDiv = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Attributes.Contains("class") && _.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("featured_image"));
var img = featureDiv.ChildNodes.First(_ => _.Name.Equals("img"));
var imgUrl = img.Attributes["src"];
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this way and it had no speed improvement over the original code. Could this have something to do with the fact that I'm behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: Yep, I think that's the only issue here.